# django class based view has no reverse

Tags: django, django-urls

I was trying out the url template tag and stumbled on a issue:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for ''location'' with arguments 
'(<City: New York>,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

In my template file I have:

```
{% url 'location' city_name=city.name %}
```

url.py

```
url(r'^location/(?P<city_name>.*)/$', CityView.as_view(), name="location"),
```

models.py

```
def get_absolute_url(self):                                                                                                                                                                               
    return "/location/%s" % self.name
```

Comment: are you using {% load url from future %}?

Comment: Most likely, you referenced the code for your `{% url %}` tag from the docs, which generally default to the dev version. Django 1.4+ institutes a new-style `url` template tag, which breaks compability with older versions of Django. Always make sure the docs are set to your running version Django.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated thanks to [Maik Hoepfel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/753738/maik-hoepfel) in the comments:

Pre Django-1.5, You don't need the `'` marks in:

```
{% url 'location' city_name=city.name %}
```

however you can enable them by loading `url` from the future module. Rather than `{% load url %}` use `{% load url from future %}`.

In your case, pre-Django 1.5 and without the future version of url, you can use:

```
{% url location city_name=city.name %}
```

I suspect it can't find your name value because it is literally looking for `'location'`.

Comment: Note that starting with Django 1.5, you will need the quotation marks. And from Django 1.3 onwards it was possible to use quotation marks if you do {% load url from future %}.

Comment: @Maik. Thanks, I'm currently in the process of updating a project or two in anticipation of the 1.5 release so that helps me, as well as making this answer better!

Comment: https://github.com/futurecolors/django-future-url/ makes the transition painless.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am new here, so I can't tell if this solved your problem already. In case it is not solved yet, the errormessage looks to me that it says you have positionell-arguments and no keyword-arguments.

The reverse function is looking for a view witch accepts keyword-arguments. The urls.py entry is creating a keyword-argument ?P.

Please check if you have another entry in urls.py which is using positional-arguments like (.*) without the ?P<...>

Background: It is not possible to use positionell and keyword arguments at the same time.